# Saber si en un fichero ha cambiado su contenido con Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

En mi servidor `Node.js` necesitaría saber si el contenido de un archivo ha sido modificado, y en caso de ser cierto, leerlo y enviarlo por medio de `socket.io`. El código que tengo, tan solo lee el contenido la primera vez (cuando se recarga la página).

```
init = function (server_created) {
    var listen = io.listen(server_created);
    listen.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        myReadFile(socket);
    });
};

function myReadFile(socket) {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    socket.emit('number', { number: data });
});
```

Comment: Utiliza `fs#watchFile` https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener

Answer (score 1):

Fs tiene un método nativo para ese propósito, desde modificación de un archivo hasta saber si se modificó una carpeta/directorio. Coloco el código de ejemplo en su [doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html):

```
fs.watch('somedir', (eventType, filename) => {


 console.log(`event type is: ${eventType}`);
  if (filename) {
    console.log(`filename provided: ${filename}`);
  } else {
    console.log('filename not provided');
  }
});
```

Obviamente debes importarlo.

Ya puedes enviar el socket dentro del evento

Comment: Es mejor usar watchFile (aunque rinda menos) por el momento debido a problemas de compatibilidad de watch aún no resueltas en Node 8.x. Esta API aún no es 100% multiplataforma.

Answer (score 0):

> Necesitaría saber si el contenido de un archivo ha sido modificado.

Para eso puedes leer la metadata del archivo, en concreto el campo *last modified*, el cual se accede por medio de *mtime*. También es necesario saber la fecha de creación (*ctime*).

```
const checkIfWasModified = (path) => (
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
    const { ctime, mtime } = stats;
    if (ctime === mtime) {
      resolve(false);
    } else {
      resolve(true);
    }
  })
});
```

Solo tendrías que hacer:

```
const hasChanged = await checkIfWasModified('<ruta al archivo>');
if (hasChanged) { // ha cambiado, enviar el archivo }
else { // hacer otra cosa }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, en el lado del servidor importamos [**`fs#watch`**](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html):

```
const { watch } = require('fs');
```

Y creamos la lógica para emitir el evento a los usuarios:

```
watch('./public/dummy.txt')
.addListener('change', (eventType, filename) => {
  //console.log(eventType, filename);
  io.emit('file:change');
});
```

Luego en el lado del cliente, escuchamos a los eventos `connect` y `file:change`.

> Nota : `cache: 'no-store'` sirve para forzar a que se haga una petición al recurso y evitar que se use el recurso contenido en el cache. [Más información](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('window:load')
    const socket = io();

    async function loadFile(){
        console.log('file:change');
        let txt = await 
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/dummy.txt', { cache: 'no-store' })
            .then( res => res.text() );

        document.body.textContent = txt;
    }

    socket.on('connect', loadFile);
    socket.on('file:change', loadFile);
</script>
```

Respuesta a una pregunta parecida en [**`SO`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45220141/3866134).

Comment: Es mejor usar watchFile (aunque rinda menos) por el momento debido a problemas de compatibilidad de watch aún no resueltas en Node 8.x. Esta API aún no es 100% multiplataforma